# OS X: -webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: For WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

Cocoa Touch framework for iOS devices has a class called `UIWebView` and protocol called `UIWebViewDelegate`. This protocol has method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Currently I am trying to create an OS X Application with `WebView`inside. I need a method which should be called **BEFORE** `WebView` is loaded, which could at access a request and would let (or not) to proceed a request to load a `WebView`. Is there any protocol or other way to have this functionality in Cocoa framework?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the WebFrameLoadDelegate protocol for the WebView class.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/

Comment: And which method from there I should use? And how, should I implement required features described above?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set `frameLoadDelegate`. Than you can use `(void)webView:(WebView *)sender
didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame` method. This method called when a web frame recieve a request . Something like this:

```
(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame{
       if(myWebView.mainFrameURL==@"http://sample.url")
       {
           [myWebView stopLoading:nil];
       }
}
```

Comment: I see `[myWebView stopLoading:nil];` does this cancel current request?

Comment: Is there any method to be executed BEFORE sending HTTP request?